# MadelineProto connect to MySQL issues

Tags: php, telegram

I'm trying to keep MadelineProto data to database.

I have configured MySQL as described in [this](https://docs.madelineproto.xyz/docs/DATABASE.html) guide. Always getting the error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Amp\Sql\ConnectionException: Unsupported
> protocol version 255 (Expected: 10)

Code example:

```
$database = new \danog\MadelineProto\Settings\Database\Mysql();
$database->setUri('172.22.208.1:3306');
$database->setUsername('wsl_root');
$database->setPassword('1');
$database->setDatabase('tg_app');
$settings = new Settings();
$settings->setDb($database);
$MadelineProto = new API('session.madeline', $settings);
```

Host and port 100% correct. Allowed from firewall. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `$database->setUri('tcp://172.22.208.1:3306');` ?

Comment: I tried all possible variants. With `tcp`, without port. `localhost`, `127.0.0.1` instead host and many other variants. Nothing helped. Just if I specify `33060` port I get error `Unsupported protocol version 11 (Expected: 10)` . `11` instead `255`.

Comment: Make sure you're using MariaDb 10.2+ or Mysql 5.6+.

If this is still happening, report the issue to https://github.com/amphp/mysql

Answer (score 0):

add tcp:// in begining of database uri like this tcp://172.22.208.1:3306

```
$settings->setDb((new Mysql)->setUri(DB_URI)->setDatabase(DB_NAME)->setUsername(DB_USER)->setPassword(DB_PASSWORD));
```